# Same widgets on each page Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can i avoid same widgets on each page.I add widget on sidebar in widget area but it appears on all the pages having sidebar.I want different widgets on different pages sidebars.How can i do this.I am new to wordpress.

Comment: Use [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/) or similar plugin.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the [Jetpack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/) plugin. Once activated you can choose what [widgets](http://jetpack.me/support/widget-visibility/) display on what pages:

> The Widget Visibility module enables you to configure widgets to appear only on certain pages (or be hidden on certain pages) by using the Visibility panel.

[image]

> Visibility is controlled by five aspects: page type, category, tag, date, and author. For example, if you wanted the Archives widget to only appear on category archives and error pages, choose “Show” from the first dropdown and then add two rules: “Page is 404 Error Page” and “Category is All Category Pages.”

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the [Custom Sidebars](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-sidebars/) plugin. It comes with less overhead than Jetpack, but if you need any of the other features Jetpack provides: go for it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Display Widgets](http://wordpress.org/plugins/display-widgets/) WordPress plugin. It is a super light weight plugin and will do exactly what you want!